# This code of mine is showing floating point error.. can anyone please exlain

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
   float a = 5, b = 2;
   int c;
   c = a % b;
   printf("%d", c);
}
```

I am getting floating point error n this program-me..
someone please explain this..

Comment: Side note: Please note indentation I given in your code. Additionally its good practice to add single space after `;` and `'`, similarly an expression `a=b` should be written like `a = b;` so that your code become readable. Soon read [help-center](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17773403/revisions)

Comment: `main()` also returns an `int`.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths His program is invalid under c99 (as you said).

Comment: @TheBlueCat: it's invalid under C89, too, which allowed you to implicitly declare an `int` return type for `main()`, but not to declare a `void` return type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operands of the operator `%` have to be integral (i.e. `int`, `byte`, ...). You will have to cast the `float`s first:

```
c = ((int)a) % ((int) b);
```

Answer (score 7):

You can only use `%` operator with integer operands. Use `fmod` function (declared in `math.h`) for floating point operands.

Comment: hi `fmod()` returns remainder not modules **?** I read it [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/fmod/)  also try a [code](http://codepad.org/ZI7AIbzd)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan yes, `fmod` is a remainder and not a modulo function.  The sign of `fmod` returned value is the sign of the first argument passed to the function.

Comment: Thanks Ouah!! , then I think my answer is helpful more, you covered here all I posted my answer because I thought remainder and fmod are not same. Thanks!

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan what I meant is `fmod` is a remainder function but the C functions `remainder` and `fmod` are not equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of "remainder" is only applicable to integer division. i.e. division that required to generate integer quotient.

In `older` languages the `%` operator was just defined as `integer modular division`.  Quite a few early C compilers didn't support `floating point` at all. It was added on later, and most primitive operations supported in the language, but everything else left to the `standard library.`

For floating point numbers, a new operation is required that would generate integer quotient for floating point operands.

Core C language does not support such operation, but it is provided as a standard library `fmod` function, as well as `remainder` function in C99.